# Override Values in Insertion in Nested Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I usually work in Java and I am new to C#. I would like to store a `<key , value>` pair to save client information. In Java, I use `Map`, I C# `Dictionary`.

During insertion in a nested dictionary, C# overrides the previous innerDictionary record.

Here is my code

```
if (! outerDictionary.TryGetValue(senderID, out innerDictionary))
{
    innerDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    if (!innerDictionary.ContainsKey(numMessages))
    {
         outerDictionary.Add(senderID, innerDictionary);
         innerDictionary.Add(numMessages,txtSendMessage.Text);
    }
 }
```

Here Is Output

```
Sender ID = 1
Messages Count=2  Message Body:: Java Developer
....................................................
Sender ID = 1
Messages Count=3  Message Body:: Python Developer
Sender ID = 2
Messages Count=3  Message Body:: Python Developer
....................................................
```

Desire Output

```
Sender ID = 1
Messages Count=2  Message Body:: Java Developer
Sender ID = 2
Messages Count=3  Message Body:: Python Developer
....................................................
```

Comment: you are newing up an instance of innerDictionary.... this is probably why you appear to be "overriding" the previous value. To update it, simply access the key for the innerDictionary and set its value i.e: innerDictionary[1] = "Some new value";

Comment: @Ahmedilyas that's actually fine because he uses TryGetValue and if that method returns false, there is no key/value pair in the dictionary. What bothers me is the second if statement. There is no way that is ever going to return 'true'. Also where are subsequent values added? Meaning, where is the 'else' block for the first/outer if statement?

Comment: But Without newing up an instance of innerDictionary , It throws  Null Pointer exception (Reference to Null Object)

Comment: oh also the method producing the output would be nice and what the expected output should look like. Because currently, the output looks fine to me.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler , Currently , Assuming Sender ID will be unique

Comment: The Desired Output should be                                                                     [Sender ID = 1   Messages Count=2  Message Body:: Java Developer]
[Sender ID = 2   Messages Count=3  Message Body:: Python Developer]
....................................................

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I hope you got it my point as per desired output

Comment: You don't show the code when `outerDictionary` *does* contain an item with `senderID` key. You do understand how `TryGetValue` works, right? And I don't understand why `numMessages` is the key for the inner dictionary. What's the point of that? Don't you want to use a list for the inner collection instead?

Comment: @KiranChoudhary but that's the exact output you show in your question. Also there's still code missing from your question. Please re-read my first comment. Also "Currently , Assuming Sender ID will be unique", in a dictionary the key is always unique.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I got it sir , i just debug it , there was problem in foreach loop for print values , Now i solve the issue  ,Thanks for ur answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
if (!outerDictionary.ContainsKey(senderID))
{
    outerDictionary[senderID] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}
outerDictionary[senderID][numMessages] = txtSendMessage.Text;
```